# Sizing Leaflet Map inside bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, leaflet

I have been trying to change the height of my leaflet map to a percentage inside of bootstrap but everytime I do the map will not draw. Thus, I always have to revert to px value.  I'm pretty sure its a simple setting that I'm missing since I am a CSS novice. Here is my css.

```
<style type="text/css">
  body {
    padding-top: 60px;
    padding-bottom: 40px;
  }
  #map {
    height: 75%;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: A working answer on the [GIS StackExchange site](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/62491/sizing-leaflet-map-inside-bootstrap)

Comment: It seems that we both have the same issue. Can't seem to figure out how to stretch the leaflet map to cover the entire bootstrap container [template_img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vjSju.png). I tried the answers below and few other answers on the Internet, but none has work so far. Here are my html [html_img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/81nNv.png) and my CSS [css_img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oUUgJ.png). Are there other workarounds to fix my issue? especially without using javascript since I'm a newbie and don't know about Javascript. I'm Rendering the map using folium inside a Django app btw.

Answer (score 3):

Try adding a `height` property to `body` or parent container.

Answer (score 2):

**CCS**

```
#map
{
    width: 100px;
    height:100px;
    min-height: 100%;
    min-width: 100%;
    display: block;
}

html, body
{
    height: 100%;
}

.fill
{
    min-height: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    min-width: 100%;
}
```

**html**

```
<div class="container fill">
     <div id="map">

     </div> 
 </div>
```

Comment: Why set min-height and min-width if they are fixed with width and height?

Answer (score 1):

With CSS from project [Bootleaf](https://github.com/bmcbride/bootleaf) on Github:

```
html,body, #map{
    height:100%;
    width: 100%;
overflow: hidden;
}
body {
    padding-top: 50px;
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to setting the height property of the map div to 100% you might need to implement [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10762984/leaflet-map-not-displayed-properly-inside-tabbed-panel) to ensure that the map fills the div on a resize.

Answer (score 0):

```
body {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
html, body, #map, .row-fluid{
    height: 100%;
}

#map {
    width: 100%;
}

.height-css
{
    height: 100%;
}
```

your html will be

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="span12 height-css">
         <div id="map"></div> 
     </div>
   </div>
</div>
```