# Leafleft map not showing on mobile device

Tags: mobile, dictionary, leaflet

The map shows if it just a normal map but does not show when the location service is added to show the users current position

I had tried the fix for this

```
 <script>
    $("#dashboard").on("next", "click", function(event, ui)
       { 
          map.invalidateSize(false);
       });
 </script>
```

[Leaflet map not displayed properly inside tabbed panel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10762984/leaflet-map-not-displayed-properly-inside-tabbed-panel)

but this does not work. It only shows a tiny piece of the map in the top left hand corner and also destroys the initial zoom and is zoomed out to the max.

If i pan the map it will briefly show a section of the map and then disappear. The added marker is set though.

http://jsfiddle.net/JRhCB/

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get it to work by wrapping the whole map creation in a function mapInit() and then i just called that function on the button click that showed that section of the page. Zoom , location, options and the display of the map all work 100%.