# How can I fix bootstrap leaflet map mobile display?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, mobile, leaflet, mapbox, window-resize

I'm using bootstrap to set up a leaflet map. Works great on browsers so far, but does not display at all on a mobile.

Tried the invalidateSize(); work around to no avail ([Leaflet map not displayed properly inside tabbed panel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10762984/leaflet-map-not-displayed-properly-inside-tabbed-panel))

See code below.

```
    <body>
      <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse"><span class="icon-bar"></span></button>
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="http://www.url.com">hello!!!</a>
        </div>
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li> <a href="#aboutModal" data-toggle="modal"> <i class="fa fa-connectdevelop" style="color: white"></i> Info</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div><!--/.navbar-collapse -->
      </div> <!-- navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top -->

      <div id="map"></div>

      <div class="modal fade" id="aboutModal">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
          <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-body">
              <ul id="aboutTabs" class="nav nav-tabs">
                <li class="active"> <a href="#about" data-toggle="tab"><i class="fa fa-bookmark"></i>About this GeoPortal</a></li>
                <li> <a href="#disclaimer" data-toggle="tab"><i class="fa fa-info-circle"></i>Disclaimer</a></li>
                <li><a href="#legend1" data-toggle="tab"><i class="fa fa-barcode"></i>Legend</a></li>
              </ul>
              <div id="aboutTabsContent" class="tab-content" style="padding-top: 10px; text-indent: 0px; -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px; box-shadow: 0px 0px; margin-right: autopx; margin-left: auto; margin-top: auto; margin-bottom: auto; padding-left: 0px; /* [disabled]border-color: #D1D1D1; */">
                <div class="tab-pane fade active in" id="about">
                    <p>This says something.</p>
                </div>
                <div class="tab-pane fade text-danger" id="disclaimer">
                  <p>something here</p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
        </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
      </div><!-- /.modal -->

      <script>
        L.mapbox.accessToken = 'token';
          var map = L.map('map').setView([10.5063,-61.4079], 10);
          var streets = L.mapbox.tileLayer('url').addTo(map);
          var drivetimes = L.mapbox.tileLayer('url');
          var outlets = L.mapbox.tileLayer('url');
          var layer1={"Streets":streets};
          var layer2={"Drive Times":drivetimes,"Outlets":outlets};
          var layerControl=L.control.layers(layer1,layer2).addTo(map);
          map.attributionControl.setPrefix('&copy;<a href="http://www.myurl.com">Copyright 2006-2015. hello!!! Limited</a>');
          L.control.locate().addTo(map);

          if(document.body.clientWidth<=767){var isCollapsed=true}else{var isCollapsed=false}var sidebar=L.control.sidebar("sidebar",{closeButton:true,position:"left"}).addTo(map);
          if(navigator.appName=="Microsoft Internet Explorer"){$("input").each(function(){if($(this).val()==""&&$(this).attr("placeholder")!=""){$(this).val($(this).attr("placeholder"));
          $(this).focus(function(){if($(this).val()==$(this).attr("placeholder"))$(this).val("")});
          $(this).blur(function(){if($(this).val()=="")$(this).val($(this).attr("placeholder"))})}})}
      </script>
    </body>
```

this is the main css file:

```
    html, body, #map {height: 100%;width: 100%;overflow: hidden;}
    body {padding-top: 50px;}
    input[type="radio"], input[type="checkbox"] {margin: 0;}
    #loading {position: absolute; width: 220px; height: 19px; top: 50%; left: 50%; margin: -10px 0 0 -110px; z-index: 20001;}
    .leaflet-control-layers label { font-weight: normal; margin-bottom: 0px;}
    .table { margin-bottom: 0px;}
    .navbar .navbar-brand { font-weight: bold; font-size: 25px; color: #3CFF8F!important;}
    .navbar-collapse.in { overflow-y: hidden;}
    .typeahead { background-color: #FFFFFF;}
    .tt-dropdown-menu { background-color: #FFFFFF; border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2); border-radius: 4px 4px 4px 4px; box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2); margin-top: 4px; padding: 4px 0; width: 100%; max-height: 300px; overflow: auto;}
    .tt-suggestion { font-size: 14px; line-height: 20px; padding: 3px 10px;}
    .tt-suggestion.tt-cursor { background-color: #0097CF; color: #FFFFFF; cursor: pointer;}
    .tt-suggestion p { margin: 0;}
    .tt-suggestion + .tt-suggestion { border-top: 1px solid #0097CF;}
    .typeahead-header { margin: 0 5px 5px 5px; padding: 3px 0; border-bottom: 2px solid #333;}
    .has-feedback .form-control-feedback { position: absolute; top: 0; right: 0; display: block; width: 34px; height: 34px; line-height: 34px; text-align: center;}
    .leaflet-popup-content { margin-top: 1px; margin-bottom: 1px; margin-left: 2px; margin-right: 2px; background:#000!important; font-weight:bold; font-family:Gotham, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;}
    .leaflet-popup-content-wrapper { border-radius: 0px; border-color:transparent!important; border:none; opacity:0.7; color:#fff!important; size:auto!important;}
    .leaflet-sidebar { z-index: 1020;}
    .leaflet-sidebar .close { right: 0px; top: 5px; background: transparent;}
    .leaflet-control-locate {border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.4);}
    .leaflet-control-locate a {background-color: #fff;background-position: -3px, -2px;}
    .leaflet-control-locate.active a {background-position: -33px -2px;}
    @media (max-width: 992px) { .navbar .navbar-brand {font-size: 18px; }}
    @media (max-width: 767px){ .url-break {word-break: break-all;     word-break: break-word;-webkit-hyphens: auto;hyphens: auto; }}
    @media print { .navbar {display: none !important; } .leaflet-control-container {display: none !important; }}
```

Comment: Tried the map using a mapbox template for a leaflet layer switcher. Still does not display on a mobile.

Comment: Could you post the relevant CSS? Do you get any errors in your console?

Comment: @iH8 css added. also flagged the same issue [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28868124/proper-implementation-of-invalidatesize-to-display-mapbox-leaflet-on-mobile-de)

Comment: @iH8 no errors. Map displays perfectly fine on a desktop browser. Resizes as should. However. It will not display on a mobile phone, particularly iphone. (Edited for spelling error)

Comment: This thread relates to [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/q/28868124/3344494)

Comment: the maps now work. the issue was http/https. two things had to be changed. 1) the method of calling the tiles and associated php script initially, i used tileserver.php to call 'Streets':L.tileLayer('[url]url/[mbtiles file name].tilejson' now i'm using mbtiles-server.php to call 'Streets':L.tileLayer("[url]/mbtiles-server.php?db=[mbtiles file name].mbtiles&z={z}&x={x}&y={y}.png") the php script had to be in the same folder/directory as the mbtiles file. replace text in [] with your own 2) leaflet only, no mapbox as the api uses a secure key thanks again @iH8! excellent work!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the maps now work.

the issue was http/https. two things had to be changed.

1) the method of calling the tiles and associated php script initially, i used tileserver.php to call

```
'Streets':L.tileLayer('[url]url/[mbtiles file name].tilejson'
```

now i'm using mbtiles-server.php to call

```
'Streets':L.tileLayer("[url]/mbtiles-server.php?db=[mbtiles file name].mbtiles&z={z}&x={x}&y={y}.png")
```

note: php script had to be in the same folder/directory as the mbtiles file. also, replace text in [] with your own

2) leaflet css/js was used only, no mapbox as the api uses a secure key

much thanks again @iH8 for the excellent work!